# How to check if a time range is greater than a 7 week time range using jquery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've startdate and enddate with a 7 week timerange. I'm trying to check for a condition when the range is greater than 7 days, i'd like to apply different timeFormat to it: Ex:
Js:

```
startdate = "2015-07-04T00:00:00";
 enddate = "2015-07-11T23:59:59";  //range 7 days
 //pseudo code:
  if (difference between (startdate & enddate)  > 7){
     //set timeFormat = "30days"
 }else{
   //set timeFormat = "7days"
 }
```

any ideas on how to achieve this?? Thanks!

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi brother take a look to this solution, hope that help you :

```
var startdate = new Date("2015-07-04T00:00:00");
var enddate = new Date("2015-07-11T23:59:59");

var timeDifference  = Math.abs(enddate.getTime() - startdate.getTime());
var differenceDays = Math.ceil(timeDifference  / (1000 * 3600 * 24));  //return 8

  if (differenceDays > 7){
     //set timeFormat = "30days"
 }else{
   //set timeFormat = "7days"
 }
```

This is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pzu5hfrp/1/).

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like

```js
var startdate = new Date( "2015-07-04T00:00:00");
var enddate = new Date( "2015-07-11T23:59:59");
var timeDiff = Math.abs(enddate.getTime() - startdate.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
alert(diffDays);
 //pseudo code:
  if (diffDays  > 7){
     //set timeFormat = "30days"
    alert(3);
 }else{
   //set timeFormat = "7days"
   alert(7)
 }
```